# visual studio 2013 update 2 taking to long to configur

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

I have installed visual studio 2013 version 2 and my installation process is stuck and its not giving me any error...

Help me what should I do?

[image: Installation process]

Comment: Search for the Installation logfile and read it or post it here

Comment: @Marged - I'm new to visual studio. Can you please help me find Installation logfile. I can not find it in any of the installation folder created in program files.

Comment: When you run this http://aka.ms/vscollect all log files will be collected and stored in %temp%

Comment: @Marged - hey thanks for helping me out. I found solution to this. Now my    visual studio is installed correctly.

Comment: You can always upvote my comments in order to say thanks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If installation process is stuck then wait for long time. Some times it happens that it takes too long.

Or just cancel the installation process and re-start. There are exactly no solution to this. There is no such problem that we can solve while this installation is going on.

Advice you to not to try any thing foolish which will change your system configuration and your other application will misbehave.